# How to change base class and keep same implementation in C#

Tags: c#, .net

The question is very easy to understand, but I couldn't find an elegant way to solve this problem. Let's say I have implemented

```
public partial class PluginControl : ClientTabControlPlugin
{
    ...
}
```

Note it's a partial class because it's partly created with Windows Forms Designer.

Now I want to implement this:

```
public partial class PluginControl(2) : ContactTabControlPlugin
{
    ...
}
```

I.e., (almost) same implementation but different base class. Note I am forced to do it in order to make each class available as plugin for the software I am using.

How can I solve this without creating a copy of the PluginControl implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that, C#  has no multiple inheritance.

You can of course favor composition over inheritance and use shared classes:

```
public partial class PluginControl : ClientTabControlPlugin
{
    public Foo DoFoo(Bar bar)
    {
        return new Foo(bar);
    }
}

public partial class PluginControl(2) : ContactTabControlPlugin
{
    public Foo DoFoo(Bar bar)
    {   
        return new Foo(bar);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(bar)
    {
        // shared implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I Dont think there's any elegant way to solve this in c#, but one option is to create a third class which contains all the actual logic, and then it the implementation of each method in each control simply call the matching method in an instance of the third class.

Another option is to add an interface to both control classes and put all the shared logic in extension methods.

Comment: Extension methods don't implement interfaces. OP is using a plugin system, where the hosting application most likely will call methods like `ClientTabControlPlugin.Render()`.

Comment: @CodeCaster what? I didn't say extension methods implement interfaces, I'm suggesting using an interface to expose whatever properties are needed by the logic, and then using extension methods to implement the logic and extend that interface. No reason why any calls to Render  or similar couldnt be via an extension method.

Comment: Please show some code illustrating what you mean by those extension methods.

Comment: @CodeCaster no, sorry. If the op asks me I would, but I Dont know what you're trying to achieve with this request and I'm busy.

Comment: I'm just curious how you would solve this using extension methods, but never mind then.